# Google Drive signing in on PC

Tags: google-drive-api

Why can't google drive signin for the first time after installation complete ?
Any solution?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after couple hour's asking and finding and i found.
So the problems is on IE proxy which is placed : Setting > Internet Options > Connections > **Lan Setting**

You see at Automatic configuration group, there have two boxes which is the box is untick.

So the solution is, tick "Use automatic configuration script" box then put the google address. The google address might be personal and using by certain company for their kind perusal

Then it's fixed.